# Why does disk read/write seem to half when running 2 dd processes on 4 different disks?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, dd, ddrescue, firewire

I'm trying to clone 2 external firewire disks on my debian fileserver using ddrescue.

I'm running 2 processes in 2 terminals like so:

```
sudo ddrescue -d -r3 /dev/sdx'/mnt/disk1/image1.img' '/mnt/disk1/image.loggfile'
```

and

```
sudo ddrescue -d -r3 /dev/sdz '/mnt/disk2/image2.img' '/mnt/disk2/image2.loggfile'
```

When I start the second process the first one slows down to half the speed (to around 15 M/s). The processes are reading and writing to and from different disks so I'm confused as to where the bottleneck is? Thanks

Comment: How are `/dev/sdx`, `/dev/sdz`, `/mnt/disk1` and `/mnt/disk2` connected exactly? What type are the target filesystems `/mnt/disk1` and `/mnt/disk2`?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski they are not connected: ```/mnt/disk1``` is mount point for ```/dev/sda``` like ```/mnt/disk2``` is for ```/dev/sdb```. filesystem on the externals are Apple HFS+ and the targets are XFS

Comment: You seem to have ONE shared firewire bus, with computer (hostadaptor) and at least two drives in the same bus.  That means all devices share the bandwith.  400mbit/sec firewire is pretty common and 30MB/sec total feels about right for that  (same as for USB2 480mbit/sec and typical speeds of 33MB/sec).

Comment: If you add twho independant fireware cards (or one PCIe card and one via the motherboard) this would not happen.  And vice versa if you add a third disk and try to use max bandwith then all three disks will likely provide around 10mbit/sec)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Firewire bus seems to be limited to 30 MByte/sec.

22.5.2020 17:43 CEST: Triggered by the comment of Hennes:
You are running a bus which operates differently than modern interfaces with their point to point connection.
Although running different spindles the data has to share the limited bandwith of your Firewire bus.

Comment: True. But not enough for a full answer. Why not show why this is the case on a shared 400mbit/sec bus?

Comment: Hennes, I am eagerly awaiting your "show". I won't disclose my windows experiences with Firewire at least 10 years ago because the issue is about a linux environment where performance may vary.

Comment: My days off, cleaning the house and doing nothing so slow to respond. But +1 for the "share the limited bandwith of your Firewire bus." that is way more succint than my answer.

Answer (score 2):

IEEE1394 (aka Firewire) is a shared serial bus. It is hot pluggable, elects the best bus master from all devices plugged in. It selects the best isochoronious manager. It supports asynchornous data transfer as well as reserving part of the bandwith so you were able to have a guaranteed hickup free audio or video stream. Etc etc. All of which was pretty fancy when it came out and I enjoyed writing a device driver for it for testing at Philips.

But ignoring those found memories, only one item is really important here for you: It is a **shared** serial bus.

Shared, thus if one device is communicating, then all other devices must listen.

If you have two disks then only one can send data, or two can send data half of the time.

Thus if you have one hostadaptor with 400mbit bandwidth, then you can push at most 400mbit on that single bus. E.g.

- 1x 400 mbit with one active device    (sum: 400 mbit)
- 2x 200 mbit with two active devices   (sum: 400 mbit)
- 3x 133 mbit with three active devices (sum: 400 mbit)
- 4x 100 mbit with three active devices (sum: 400 mbit)

(And yes, it is technically possible that one gets more bandwith then another. E.g. when one drive is slower then available bandwith. But that is unlikely with a HDD.)

The sum of the data transfer stays 400mbit.

400 mbit signaling on the cable is not equal to 400 mbit data transfer. There is overhead (typically about 1/5th, due to 8b:10B conversion). Which means that the maximum theorectical bandwith would be close to 40MB/sec.

Now you do not typically get that. For comparison USB uses something similar. USB2 has 480 Mbit/sec, which is 20% faster signaling and a good disk to computer speed is 35 MB/sec.  Your archived speeds here are very similar, with 30MB/sec. But that is still 30 Mbyte/sec total on that bus. Or the 2x15 MByte (again 30 MB/sec total) which you see when you plug in a second and start to read max speed from it.

This in inherent of a shared bus. You see this with Ethernet (coax), Ethernet (thick ethernet), USB, Firewire, PCI, ... and the only option to speed up is to have more independant busses.

E.g. if you added a second PCI-e based IEEE1394 hostadaptor you could plug both of them in seperate card on your computer and get 30Mb/sec on both of them.  Note into seperate cards, not separate ports on the same card, connected to the same bus.

Comment: You said: [...
400 mbit signaling on the cable is not equal to 400 mbit data transfer. There is  overhead (typically about 1/5th, due to 8b:10B conversion). Which means that the >maximum theorectical bandwith would be close to 40MB/sec.
...] Thanks alot for this explanation. I did not know this. My personal experience had been like 35 MByte/sec on a Microsoft OS.
[...Now you do not typically get that. For comparison USB uses something similar. USB2 has 480 Mbit/sec, which is 20% faster signaling and a good disk to computer speed is 35 MB/sec...]
Confirmed by my personal experience!

Comment: @Hennes thank you for explaining in detail! You were absolutely right: when I run one of the disks over usb 2.0 instead of FireWire they both read at around 35 MB/sec (which curiously is more than 2*15... maybe there is some speed lost to overhead switching between two drives on the same bus?)